# Why does generic list indexer show two behaviors

Tags: c#, generics, struct, indexer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var vs = new List<Person> { new Person(1) };
   vs[0].IncrementAge();

   Console.WriteLine(vs[0].Age);  // output: 1
}

struct Person
{
   public int Age { get; set; }

   public Person(int age) : this()
   {
      Age = age;
   }

   public int IncrementAge()
   {
      Age++;
      return Age;
   }
}
```

I understand why we get a result like it. The list indexer returns a copy of the element. That is okay.

My question is that why we don't get the same result in the following code? because I changed the value of a copy of an element:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

   var vs = new List<int> { 1 };
   vs[0] = 2;

   Console.WriteLine(vs[0]);     // output: 2, **why not 1?**
}
```

Why does overwriting the entire value of a copy of an element affect list? I want to know how this code works in the background.

Comment: Well, in the second case you overwrite the entire value in list, in first you update the internal state of struct

Comment: You reassigned the content of the item in the list, instead of modifying the copy. It would be similar for your first example if you did `vs[0] = new Person(2);`.

Comment: This is why mutable structs are bad.  `int` is not mutable so in your attempt to show mutation you ended up correctly using reassignment that "worked" vs. the mutable `Person` struct that allowed you to mutate a copy and create code that is confusing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I know that. I wanted to write simple and understandable code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
vs[0].IncrementAge();
```

you *retrieve* the value at index 0, which creates a *copy* of the `struct`. In the copy, the `Age` gets incremented, and the copy is *then lost*. It is not saved back into the list.

In this context, `vs[0]` is translated to calling a getter method which returns a value. It would be the same as (pseudocode):

```
vs.get_Item(0).IncrementAge();
```

On the contrary, here:

```
vs[0] = 2;
```

you *replace* the value at position 0 with a new one. That's why it's changed *in the list*.

In this context, `vs[0]` is translated to calling a setter method which stores the provided value into the list's internal data structure. It would be the same as (pseudocode):

```
vs.set_Item(0, 2);
```

Comment: I can say I replace copy of element in second case

Comment: No, you don't replace a copy of element. You rather assign a value into a memory location. On the contrary, in the first case a copy is created in a _temporary_ memory location, which is then lost.

Comment: @Eldeniz keep in mind that when you use an indexer on the left of an assignment that it's calling an internal set method whereas if you use it as part of an expression it will call a get method instead.

Comment: @juharr Your comment is clear to understand how to work it. Thanks

Comment: Added more technical details regarding the getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

The array indexer returns a reference to the array element and the array value will be changed but the list value will not. The list indexer returns a copy of the element. The member function is called on this temp object. So, the original list member is not changed at all.